Gmail Javi API batch too many requests
I am using the Java Gmail API to retrieve some email messages. Once I get a list of messages, I am using batching to get the individual messages info.
Sample code as follows:
 List<MessageDto> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    String nextPageToken = null;

    List<Message> batchMessages = new ArrayList<Message>();
    ListMessagesResponse response =
            gmailClient(googleId)
                    .users()
                    .messages()
                    .list(googleId)
                    .setQ(query)
                    .setPageToken(pageToken)
                    .setMaxResults(maxResults == null ? 50 : maxResults)
                    .execute();

    if (response.getMessages() != null) {
        batchMessages.addAll(response.getMessages());
        nextPageToken = response.getNextPageToken();

        final JsonBatchCallback<Message> callback =
                new JsonBatchCallback<Message>() {
                    public void onSuccess(Message message, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
                        messages.add(MessageMapper.getMessage(googleId, message, false));
                    }

                    public void onFailure(GoogleJsonError e, HttpHeaders responseHeaders) {
                        log.error("Could not process message ", e);
                     
                    }
                };
        BatchRequest batch = gmailClient(googleId).batch();
           

        for (Message message : batchMessages) {
            gmailClient(googleId)
                    .users()
                    .messages()
                    .get(googleId, message.getId())
                    .setFormat("raw")
                    .queue(batch, callback);
        }
        batch.execute();
    }

The problem I am having is that not all the batch messages are retrieved due to too many requests and falling into the onFailure method.
I tried setting a HttpBackOffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler on the HttpRequestInitializer but that did not work.
I stumbled upon on this in the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-api-client/latest/com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch
There is a note saying:

Note: When setting an HttpUnsuccessfulResponseHandler by calling to
HttpRequest#setUnsuccessfulResponseHandler, the handler is called for
each unsuccessful part. As a result it's not recommended to use
HttpBackOffUnsuccessfulResponseHandler on a batch request, since the
back-off policy is invoked for each unsuccessful part.

Is there anyway how I can handle the too many requests exception and retry the request?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Is the error code youy are getting is 429 error? If it's 429 you can check this documentation Resolve a 429 error: Too many requests. The documentation also suggests to Retry failed requests to resolve errors

As an addition you can also check this github interaction that discusses same issues as yours

@George not sure how .net client would help someone using Java you cant be sure they can read java.  This is a known issue with batching you cant retry a failed request within a batch request to do that you have to figure out which ones failed and which didnt there is no out of the box way of doing that.  An error is an error it doesn't tell you which one in the batch.

batching doesn't save you anything except the http call its still going to cost the same to your quota.
When you send a batch of say 50 requests (it depends on the api how many you can send in a batch)  all of those requests hit the server at the same time and are run.  This means that batching can result in many flooding type errors which i think you are seeing.   You wont always get them because if the server you land on is busy then it may take it time to process your requests. However if you manage to land on a server that is not busy they could all run in record time and you will then get an error saying your flooding.
The recommendations i normally give my clients are.

don't bother batching.
If you really must batch keep the number low try 10 if you still get errors try

If you do get errors its hard to know which ones were sent and which errored out in the batch on some apis. You will need to configure a system to check if the change was made and if not then send it in the next batch.  This alone is why i recommend not batching.

Thanks for the insight Linda. Essentially I  wanted to reduce the network chattiness but was unware the existing quota would still apply. I also noticed that theres no easy way to identify which ones failed. Even so, I would have to write bespoke code to retry those as the backoff exponential is no use. I'll refactor the code and remove the batching for now.

Yeah sorry but its for the best. I have wasted so much time on it myself.
